# Page loads only on certain computers

Tags: apache, nginx, debian

since now, I used my server only for education purposes and for encoding video. Now i wanted to try to host some site on it (for my friend) using nginx and apache, but the problem is, that even though it successfully loads on my computer, and some other ones too, I also have seen that the page didn't load and instead of it was showing just the "Welcome to nginx on debian" page.
How can i make it work everytime?

/etc/nginx/sites-available/uterfleru.cz :

```
server {
  listen          80;

  root /var/uterfleru.cz;
  index index.html index.php index.htm;

  server_name uterfleru.cz;
}
```

DNS - A:

```
uterfleru.cz    64.188.46.67
www.uterfleru.cz    64.188.46.67
```

64.188.46.67 is ipv4 of my server,
http://uterfleru.cz/ is the webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`server_name uterfleru.cz;` means exactly `uterfleru.cz` domain name. To make this `server` block working for `www` subdomain you have to modify it [like that](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name):

```
server_name www.uterfleru.cz uterfleru.cz;
```

To make it work with any subdomain you have to change it to:

```
# synonym of *.uterfleru.cz uterfleru.cz;
server_name .uterfleru.cz;
```

To make this server block work by default you have to remove `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf` file and modify your `listen` directive [like that](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen):

```
listen 80 default;
```

[Official documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html) have all the information you need, it's one of the best documents for software I've ever seen and I highly recommend you learn to make use of it.